# Server health check functionality of DNS server

Tags: dns, load-balancing, high-availability

AWS Route 53 can do health checks of servers and thus it returns only healthy IPs as can be seen [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/dns-failover.html).

Which other DNS server (open source or otherwise) provides such health check functionality?

Answer (score 1):

F5 big ip, pulse vadc (originally Zeus zxtm)  do the jobs, they had dns load balancing fonctionality with health check and Geo routing and  scripting.

Polaris gslb in open source seam to also:
https://github.com/polaris-gslb/polaris-gslb